# Calling function using the get operation from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, user-input, user-defined-functions

columnType and graphType are both dictionaries of functions.  Can I call these using the get method?

```py
columnType = {1: column_set1, 2: column_set2, 3: column_set3}
graphType = {1: graph_1, 2: graph_2, 3: graph_3, 4: graph_4, 5: graph_5, 6: graph_6}

# Enter column and graph type
columnInput = input("Enter column number: ")
graphInput = input("Enter graph number: ")

columnType.get(columnInput)
graphType.get(graphInput)
```

When I run it it does not print the graphs that are in the function.

```
def graph_6():
    unemployment = data[["States", "Region", "Estimated Unemployment Rate"]]
    figure = px.sunburst(unemployment,
                         path=["Region", "States"],
                         values="Estimated Unemployment Rate",
                         width=700,
                         height=700,
                         color_continuous_scale="RdY1Gn",
                         title="Unemployment Rate in India")
    figure.show()
```

Comment: `get()` will simply return the value of the specified key (if it exists). there is no expectation that this would call a function. to call the function, use `()`

Comment: Unless you're still using Python 2.x for some reason, your `.get()` calls aren't actually retrieving a function.  `input()` returns a string, but none of your dict keys are strings.

Comment: I tried my best to fix your formatting. If it is not correct, please edit and try to not to delete the formatting I used. Simply paste your code blocks where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Since your keys are `int`s, you'll need to convert the `input()` result to an `int` in order to look up the function, and then you'll need to use `()` to call the function:

```
graphType.get(int(graphInput))()
```

or more simply:

```
graphType[int(graphInput)]()
```

Note that if `graphInput` isn't a decimal string, this will raise `ValueError`, and if it's not present in the dictionary, using `[]` will raise `KeyError`.  If you use `get()` to avoid the `KeyError`, you'll get a `TypeError` when you try to call the resulting `None`.